# Add XML editor to Eclipse Standard

Tags: xml, eclipse

I've usually downloaded the full J2EE version of Eclipse. Now I wanted to get the Standard and manually install what I need.

But I'm missing the XML Editor. Is installing the whole WTP the only way to get the Eclipse XML Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok,

- "Install new software.."
- > the default update site (in my case it's the Kepler update)
- -> Web, XML , Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
- --> Eclipse XML Editors and Tools

seems to be the minimal way of adding the XML editor back.